# Share for Twitter automatically from Android?

Tags: android, twitter

Is there a way to share a tweet from my Android app automatically (after user's login, and permissions - like the Facebook SDK)?

I searched the internet, but only found 3-4 old not updated 3rd party libs, and no docs for any.

Thanks!

Comment: It would be better if you shared your actual research, rather than just say "I searched."  Have you read this?  http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/02/13/guide-to-integrating-twitter-android-application/

Comment: Nope, didn't find this link. It seems OK, thanks for the link!

Comment: https://github.com/socialize/socialize-sdk-android

Answer (score 0):

With this you can share information with other applications, for example twitter.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setType("text/plain");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text_to_share);
```

Hope it helps you :)